# Notifications URL of Facebook comments show no comments

Tags: facebook, joomla

I'm using Joomla in my site and I had installed [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect). My problem is that when I receive a notification that someone has replied my post, the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is modified, so I can't see any comment.

Example:

Original Website is http://unionvecinalquilmes.com.ar/getting-started.html.

URL of the notification is http://unionvecinalquilmes.com.ar/getting-started.html?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150903622273242_25781034_10150903622413242#f19a826f4

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `href` of the comments plugin to your page [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). For example, use the base URL if your pages' base URL is always the current page URL.

Comment: Thanks! And if the page is dinamic? My actual code is "
 if(!$nfc_href){ 
  $nfc_href = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $nfc_href = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $nfc_href);
  $nfc_href = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $nfc_href);"

Comment: There should be a way to get your pages in Joomla other than *trust* what the user is typing (despite the security issues)! I could just add any query string to break your page (e.g. comments plugin is no longer working? :)): `http://unionvecinalquilmes.com.ar/getting-started.html?foo=bar`